# Moodle Data size freeup

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I would like to reduce my moodle data size as the size is more than 115GB, i have installed moodle 2.9.1. Please help me with the methods to reduce the size of the moodle data folder by deleting old data or unwanted data from it without affecting the working application. Also please let me know if any moodle plugins available for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Moodle 2.0 or above (you don't specify in your question).

You can probably safely remove files from the "temp" subdirectory.

It is likely, however, that the vast majority of files will be found in the "filedir" subdirectory. There is no safe way to manually remove files from here - they must be deleted via the user interface or by writing code to use the Moodle files API to delete unwanted files.

Deleting files directly from the "filedir" without allowing Moodle to also update the relevant entries in the mdl_files table will result in fatal errors if the file is accessed via the Moodle code.

I suggest you start by looking to see if there are old, unused courses that can be deleted via the Moodle interface.

Comment: Thanks davosmith, I have delete all contents from temp directory, but not much space reduced. its less than 2MB.